# Quantum State Tomography

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am trying to solve a problem on Quantum State Tomography:
The tomographic distribution is: $$\Pi(\phi,\lambda)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}}e^{-\lambda^2}$$
The state $\rho$ is to be determined and can be calculated as follows:
$$\rho=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int da db \tilde{\Pi}(\phi,\lambda)e^{ia\hat{x}+ib\hat{p}}$$
where $a=rcos(\phi)$, $b=rsin(\phi)$ and $\tilde{\Pi}(\phi,\lambda)=\int d\lambda \Pi(\phi,\lambda)e^{-i\lambda r}$ As a hint we are asked to calculate the momentum representation $\langle p_1|\rho|p_2\rangle$
By plugging into the formula for $\rho$ all the information and  changing the integration to $\int dr d\phi r$ and using the Baker Hausdorff formula (the commutator of the terms with the commutator of the two terms vanishes)
I get:
$$\langle p_1|\rho|p_2\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int dr d\phi re^{-r^2/4} e^{-ir^2} e^{-ir^2 sin(2\phi)/4}\langle p_1|e^{ircos(\phi)\hat{x}}e^{irsin(\phi)\hat{p}}|p_2\rangle$$
Applying the exponential with the momentum operator is easy since that just becomes $p_2$ and the first exponential with the position operator can  be applied by noticing that it is the generator of translations in momentum space. So finally I arrive at:
$$\langle p_1|\rho|p_2\rangle=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int dr d\phi re^{-r^2/4} e^{-ir^2} e^{-ir^2 sin(2\phi)/4} e^{-irsin(\phi)p_2}\delta(rcos(\phi)+p_2-p_1)$$
I am not sure how I am to proceed from here. As far as I know there is a formula for Dirac Deltas of functions of the variable integrated over by (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function). But since the function is periodic it would have infinite terms.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt you're integrating $\phi$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Shouldn't you only be concerned by the roots of the function in the domain of integration? (It'd still be a horrible integral, though...)

Comment: Ah of course. Yes you're right. The integration limits are from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. But as you wrote it would be horrible to integrate this. I wonder if there is a simpler method or I did something wrong.